# Checkbox not working in android with animation

Tags: java, android, xml, animation

I just created this checkbox with animation following this article https://android.jlelse.eu/using-statelistanimators-to-create-instagram-like-animation-db2676c9391 and it's not working when I call checkbox.setChecked(true) from my java code! 
I want that when I click on like button! If the dislikeButton was checked true then it must be check false. And when I click dislike button, if like was checked true then it must be check false!
Here is the checkBox XML code:

```
<CheckBox
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/save_btn"
                android:id="@+id/dislike_btn"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="12dp"
                android:background="@drawable/dislike_icon"
                android:alpha="0.8"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:button="@null"
                android:stateListAnimator="@animator/like_animation"

                android:focusable="true"
                />
            <CheckBox
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/dislike_btn"
                android:id="@+id/like_btn"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="12dp"
                android:background="@drawable/like_icon"
                android:alpha="0.8"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:button="@null"
                android:stateListAnimator="@animator/like_animation"
                android:focusable="true"
                />
```

and here is like_icon and dislike_icon code:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/dislike_icon_red"/>
    <item android:state_checked="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/dislike_icon_black"/>

</selector>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/thumps_up_red"/>
    <item android:state_checked="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/thumps_up_black"/>

</selector>
```

and the animation code:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:propertyName="scaleX"
                android:valueTo="1.525"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:propertyName="scaleY"
                android:valueTo="1.525"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:propertyName="translationZ"
                android:valueTo="4dp"
                android:valueType="floatType" />

            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:propertyName="scaleX"
                android:valueTo="1.0"
                android:startOffset="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:propertyName="scaleY"
                android:startOffset="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:valueTo="1.0"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:propertyName="translationZ"
                android:startOffset="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:valueTo="0dp"
                android:valueType="floatType" />

        </set>

    </item>

    <item>
        <set>
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:propertyName="scaleX"
                android:valueTo="1.525"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:propertyName="scaleY"
                android:valueTo="1.525"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:propertyName="translationZ"
                android:valueTo="4dp"
                android:valueType="floatType" />

            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:propertyName="scaleX"
                android:valueTo="1.0"
                android:startOffset="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:propertyName="scaleY"
                android:startOffset="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:valueTo="1.0"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:propertyName="translationZ"
                android:startOffset="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:valueTo="0dp"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
        </set>
    </item>
</selector>
```

and this is what I am calling from my java code!

```
like.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
        if (like.isChecked()){
            Log.i("ELA","like check called");
            dislike.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
});
dislike.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
        if (dislike.isChecked()){
            like.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
});
```

I tried .setOnClickListener too!

Answer (score 0):

Set the checked and unchecked states in the animator. The below example has checked state.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <set>
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:propertyName="scaleX"
                android:valueTo="1.525"
                android:valueType="floatType" />

            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:propertyName="scaleY"
                android:valueTo="1.525"
                android:valueType="floatType" />

            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:propertyName="translationZ"
                android:valueTo="4dp"
                android:valueType="floatType" />

            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:propertyName="scaleX"
                android:startOffset="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:valueTo="1.0"
                android:valueType="floatType" />

            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:propertyName="scaleY"
                android:startOffset="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:valueTo="1.0"
                android:valueType="floatType" />

            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:propertyName="translationZ"
                android:startOffset="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:valueTo="0dp"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
        </set>
    </item>
</selector>
```